# Unable to Create table through json object using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, xml

[Click here to see For Converted Json Object](https://jsfiddle.net/a5khgLeL/2/)

**Please Read My question very clear**

Hi in my code below I am trying to convert xml Data to Json Object. using converted Json Object i am trying to create a table using angularjs.
so here the problem is  i am able to bind complete converted json object {{employeeList}} but failed to load individual  atttribute of json object i.e.,{{employee.EmpId}}. finally from my observation i found when the converted json object is directly asigned to

```
$scope.Employees="Employee": [ {"EmpId": "4", "Name": "Chris", "Sex": "Male", "Phone": [ { "_Type": "Home", "__text": "564-555-0122" }, { "_Type": "Work", "__text": "442-555-0154" } ], "Address": { "Street": "124 Kutbay", "City": "Montara", "State": "CA", "Zip": "94037", "Country": "USA" } } ] }
```

the output is what I expected, but when I assign the direct result

i.e,$scope.Employees=response.data;It is not working what might be the issue.here the response.data is nothing but success function result we get here

```js
            <script>
                var app = angular.module('httpApp', []);
                app.controller('httpController', function ($scope, $http) {
                    $http.get("File1.xml",
                            {
                                transformResponse: function (cnv) {
                                    var x2js = new X2JS();
                                    var aftCnv = x2js.xml_str2json(cnv);
                                    return aftCnv;
                                }
                            })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        $scope.Employees = response.data;
                        console.log($scope.Employees);

                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="httpApp">
            <div ng-controller="httpController">
                <div ng-repeat="employeeList in Employees">
                    {{employeeList}}
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="employee in Employees.Employee">
            <td>{{employee.EmpId}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.Phone._Type}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.Phone.__text}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.Address.Street}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.Address.State}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.Phone.Zip}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.Phone._text}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.Address.Country}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[Click here..For Converted Json Object](https://jsfiddle.net/a5khgLeL/2/)

[image: Output for {{Employeelist}}]
[image: XML Image]

Comment: Update your json for the question. If I can copy your json object, I will give you an example. I can't copy from image

Comment: This is link of jsonObject https://jsfiddle.net/a5khgLeL/2/

Comment: Your JSON is invalid btw. You can't start out with Employee: [... You need to encapsulate Employe: in something like an array or object

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example based on the json provided:

**HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myApp">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>EmpId</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Sex</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in json.Employee">
                    <td>{{employee.EmpId}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Sex}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Phone[0].__text}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Address.Street}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp', [])

    .controller('myController', function ($scope) {

        $scope.json = { "Employee": [{ "EmpId": "4", "Name": "Chris", "Sex": "Male", "Phone": [{ "_Type": "Home", "__text": "564-555-0122" }, { "_Type": "Work", "__text": "442-555-0154" }], "Address": { "Street": "124 Kutbay", "City": "Montara", "State": "CA", "Zip": "94037", "Country": "USA" } }] };


    })

}());
```

Comment: As i said you before if i put my Json object directly to $scope.Employees it is working as i expected but what is problem when i directly assign response to $scope.Employees

Comment: OK. I understand. From the looks of it, you're not doing anything outside of angular so it should know about it. Try changing .success to .then. Another thing to try is using $scope.$apply() to force angular to apply the updated data

Comment: Ya even checked though it is not working but rather than using success i used then i found status code 200(i.,e OK) and also used   $scope.$apply() but not useful

Comment: @phani try what I've said with JSON.parse(response) and let me know

Comment: @cosmin no it is not working  
variable response is already a valid JsonObject. You do not have to use JSON.parse on it

Comment: @phani can you post then your JSON structure or at least first two employees?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to this.

```
<div ng-app><div ng-controller="httpController">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="employee in Employees.Employee">
        <td>{{employee.EmpId}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.Phone._Type}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.Phone.__text}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.Address.Street}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.Address.State}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.Phone.Zip}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.Phone._text}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.Address.Country}}</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: even check it before it is not working till employeelist we are geting but not{{employee.Empld}}

Comment: now check it again.employeelist is not work because we use employee object in table

Comment: before code employeelist used to work but not {{employee.Empld}}

Comment: Here is Plunkner Url. employee.Empld is working now
https://plnkr.co/edit/sRQe77A9fPzneWEAJAwU?p=preview

Comment: @ zeeshan Qurban i Hope my question is very clear that if i keep my json object directly to $scope.Employees= $scope.Employees ={
  "Employee": [some thing bla bla] ... but the problem is when i assign  $scope.Employees=response; its not working

Comment: can u provide fiddler url of this problem.because i want to see that which data populate in response object.

Answer (score 0):

There is another issue in your code. The response data resides in response.data, so besides your JSON being valid or not, you should use the following assignment:

```
$scope.Employees = response.data
```

Comment: used as u said before but there is no use

Comment: i am getting undefined in console window i.e., $scope.Employees = response.data;
                        console.log($scope.Employees);

Comment: That's probably because your JSON object is still invalid, because response data returned from $http requests in Angular is always returned in response.data . The response object contains status code, status text and headers etc as well. Try do console.log(response) and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: ya if u r talking about status code so rather than using succes function if we use ".then" function we get status code 200 though everything work fine i am not able to get individual details of an emplyee i.e., <td>{{employee.EmpId}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.Name}}</td>

Comment: Oh I see now, you're not using promises (why not?). I've posted a new answer about the correct JSON format (see above).

Answer (score 0):

Extra comment after my previous answer about response.data, because I don't see the right answer about your JSON object here yet, full answer:

ng-repeat expects a list of items, which you don't provide. Remove the encapsulating 'Employee' part from your JSON, like this:

```
$scope.Employees = [
                     {"EmpId": "4", "Name": "Chris", "Sex": "Male", "Phone": [ { "_Type": "Home", "__text": "564-555-0122" }, { "_Type": "Work", "__text": "442-555-0154" } ], "Address": { "Street": "124 Kutbay", "City": "Montara", "State": "CA", "Zip": "94037", "Country": "USA" } },
                     {"EmpId": "5", "Name": "Chris", "Sex": "Male", "Phone": [ { "_Type": "Home", "__text": "564-555-0122" }, { "_Type": "Work", "__text": "442-555-0154" } ], "Address": { "Street": "124 Kutbay", "City": "Montara", "State": "CA", "Zip": "94037", "Country": "USA" } }
                   ]
```

(I've added an extra Employee with ID 5 here, but it will work with only one employee as well, as long it's a list, objects ({}) in a list ([]).

With this JSON object you can do the following:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="employee in Employees">
     <td>{{ employee.EmpId }}</td>
     <td>{{ employee.Name }}</td>
     <td>etc ...</td>
 </tr>
```

Make sure your JSON is set up like this, encapsulating comma separated objects within a list.

Return this JSON format from your get request, and don't forget to fetch the data from response.data instead of response.

Comment: @ Keugels ur explantion is too good but i tried it good and to be clear actually i am converting xml document to json object using xml2json plugin     so please can you help me in detail

Comment: even it is not working can u help me out in detail explanation from my observation i felt there is nothing wrong in jsonobject becoz when i directly assign to $ scope.employess its work good why not when i assign  resoponse daata

Comment: I'm not sure how your library returns the JSON from XML, but you should do something like this: <employees><employee><EmpId>4</EmpId><Name>HisName</Name></employee><employee><EmpId>5</EmpId><Name>HerName</Name></employees> . Convert this to JSON and you'll probably get a JSON object back with property 'employees', which then contains the list you want to assign to $scope.Employees

Comment: @ keugels i have added my xml image please look into my question even u can see what is my json object in another image

Comment: Ah I see now where the strange JSON comes from. You're getting back an Employee object which contains a list with all its members. So when you loop over the employees, you will get a JSON object like in your OP. That's not the whole JSON object, right? In that case, you can access the name with employee[0].Name and employee[0].EmpId, etc. You can get a nicer JSON output however, by setting the configuration, see https://github.com/abdmob/x2js under 'Working with Arrays'. But without configuration, the above should work.

Comment: can u create a plunker that convert xml to json and create a table based on json object

Comment: @ Keugels Please create a plunker so it will be help full to me